# Getting return value from function within get request

Tags: node.js, axios

I am having trouble getting the return value from a function when calling it within an Express get request. Here's the code:

Exported function from JS file.

```
const someFunction = () => {
  return 'Hello';
}
```

Server.js

```
app.get('/callSomeFunction', (req, res) => {
  swipe.someFunction((results) => {
    console.log(results);
    res.send(results);
  })
})
```

Frontend React.js file.

```
callSomeFunction = () => {
  console.log('Calling someFunction.');
  axios.get('/callSomeFunction')
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
    })
}
```

I'm using axios to handle HTTP requests from the client. This is a dummy example, but when running my actual code, NodeJS processes the function, it just doesn't send it back to the front-end.

Comment: `someFunction` just returns a string, so the function you pass `someFunction` in `Server.js` will not be invoked. You could call the function when you are done in `someFunction`, e.g. `const someFunction = (callback) => { callback('Hello'); }`

Comment: @Tholle You're the best, that's it. I'm coming from C++ and I still don't know all the procedures with Javascript. Thanks so much!!!

Comment: You're welcome! I know that feeling. JavaScript callback shenanigans takes some getting used to.

Comment: No better word to describe Javascript's behavior than shenanigans lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`someFunction` just returns a string, so the function you pass to `someFunction` in `Server.js` will not be invoked.

You could call the function when you are done in `someFunction` instead:

```
const someFunction = (callback) => {
  callback('Hello');
}
```